# local folder connected with SSH from server

Tags: ssh

I am in a C programming class which we are required to use an ssh connection to the campus server in order to do the work on VIM. I don't want to use filezilla every time. I currently have to transfer the needed files to my computer then to her(my professor) drop box.

How would I create a local folder, on my desktop, that automatically saves the files from my ssh connection? I am thinking a cloud type attached folder.

Answer (score 3):

Use the sshfs

```
sshfs username@server:/directory/in/server/ /local/directory/to/mount
```

The local directory to mount need to be empty

Exemple

```
sshfs corthez@mycloudserver.com:/home/corthez/codes/ /home/corthez/sshfs/codes
```